# laravel ajax and delete route not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

**My blade**

```
                              <a href="{{ route('artist_genre_delete',['id' => $genre->id]) }}" class="text-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" id="delete" title="Delete"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i></a>
```

**my ajax**

```
jQuery('#delete').click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
               $.ajaxSetup({
                              headers: {
                                   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                      }
                            });
               jQuery.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                type: 'GET',
                 success: function(result){
                     console.log("Sucess");
                  }});
               });

            });
```

**My route**

```
         Route::get('genre_delete/{id}', 'GenreController@genre_delete')->name('artist_genre_delete');
```

**1-Here i am using Ajax to delete only working first row data how to solve this problem**

**2-and anther one is  i am change to route get to delete 405 method not allowed error show.why delete mehod not working.but Get method working fine**

Comment: Shouldn't it be a 'POST' type?

Comment: Type 'DELETE' would also work. 'GET' however won't

Comment: i am change type delete but its show error 405

Comment: To clarify, you defined a route that deletes a resource as `Route::get` instead of `Route::delete` this is a very bad idea because (a) get routes are not protected by CSRF (b)  GET routes may be preloaded by browsers causing resources to disappear for no apparent reason (though this is probably rare) (c) if your route deletes a resource use a DELETE request, that's what they are there for. Now for your actual issue, the code you share only shows you deleting a single `$genre` so "deleting the first row only" seems to be your intended behaviour based on your code

Comment: add controller code too. I think there is some mistake

Comment: You have button click #id change for .class in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delete method.

Try this

**web.php**

```
Route::delete('genre_delete/{id}', GenreController@genre_delete)->name('artist_genre_delete');
```